Confused about KuhnMunkres algorithm
//minval is the minimum of the uncovered items
if (row_covered_[i]) {
        cost_matrix_(i, j) += minval;
}
if (!col_covered_[j]) {
        cost_matrix_(i, j) -= minval;
}

In many KuhnMunkres implementations, there are several lines of code like this,I understand that subtracting the smallest value is to create a new zero.
However,i dont understand why we need to add the minvalue to number which row_covered = 1 and col_covered = 1.

Here is a diagram explaining how the algorithm works.
In figure 12, we found the minimum value 1, and in figure 13, we added this value to the upper left corner of the matrix.
why we need to do this, in my point of view, the code should change to
//minval is the minimum of the uncovered items
if (!row_covered[i] && !col_covered_[j]) {
        cost_matrix_(i, j) -= minval;
}

